I want to monitor the stage value in real time to control the display and hidden of ribbon
I want to get the opportunityid for the current page,I want to monitor the stage value in real time to control the display and hidden of ribbon, but the Javascript EnableRule in ribbon will give an error, please help me see!
I want to return true or false from the function showOppBtn. I have an EnableRule in a ribbon button, which calls a custom rule that calls this function showOppBtn. On passing either true, which will show the button, or false, which will hide the button.
let showOppBtn = function (primaryControl) 
{
    var flag = false;
    var activestageidValue;
    var ReqEntityId = primaryControl.data.entity.getId().getGuid();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log('路径：'+Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/opportunitysalesprocesses?$select=_activestageid_value&$expand=opportunityid($select=opportunityid)&$filter=_opportunityid_value eq "+ ReqEntityId);
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/opportunitysalesprocesses?$select=_activestageid_value&$expand=opportunityid($select=opportunityid)&$filter=_opportunityid_value eq "+ ReqEntityId, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                activestageidValue = results.value[0]._activestageid_value;
            } else {
                console.log('监听销售流程:' + this.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
    let threeActivestageid = 'd3ca8878-8d7b-47b9-852d-fcd838790cfd';
    if(activestageidValue == threeActivestageid){
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
};


It would be helpful to post the error details, not just the code. Also, you are using an async request to get data. Please provide your Dynamics Version, as the async rule is only available in a newer version.
